# Como poner un icono a una carpeta

Tags: android, imagen

he creado una serie de carpetas, y me estaba preguntando si se pueden personalizar por un icono/imagen.

Como las que se muestran en esta imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría agregar una serie de imágenes a unas carpetas, no sé si la imagen típica de las carpetas que se muestran se pueden cambiar por otra o bien cambiar el color.

Gracias

Comment: Explica un poco mejor la pregunta, pero segun lo que entiendo podrias hacerlo superponiendo una imagen encima de la otra, tienes la de la carpeta y cambias el simbolo

Comment: @Clipi Es para hacerlo en Android, la imagen de la carpeta en Azul es la que muestra el gestor de archivos que utilizo, hay gestores que las muestra en color amarillo, pero todos esa imagen a la que apunta la flecha la del Bluetooth esta en la carpeta \data de android, ahi estan las apliaciones en sus respectivas carpetas, y todas tienen una imagen, yo quiero poner por ejemplo la imagen/icono de acrobat porque contiene documentos pero en una carpeta personal, que nada tiene que ver con lo que hay en \data, o bien poner un color rojo a toda la carpeta o otra imagen en lugar de la típica carpeta

Comment: si lo he entendido bien, ese icono te lo muestra el gestor de archivos que tu usas porque estara definidad y guardad en algun sitio, solo tendras que ver la extension del archivo que tu guardes y dependiendo de la extension lo guardas en un sitio u otro, y a la hora de visiualizarlo dependiendo de la extension o la URL donde accedas muestrad una imagen o otra, pero tendras que bajarte los iconos tu y guardarlos en algun lado

Comment: No entiendo lo de guardarlo en un sitio u otro para que saque el icono en la carpeta, y que los iconos los tenga que guardar en otra carpeta para que se muestren en la carpeta que yo quiero que los saque, la verdad es que ese ejemplo que te he mostrado con el icono del Bluetooth dentro de esa carpeta no tiene ningún archivo, la carpeta esta vacía, y si el icono tiene que estar en otra carpeta, no se si hay que configurar y como esa carpeta para que se muestre.